# Can't get ScrollView or LinearLayout to scroll on children exceeding screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I have browsed through many SO, and other forums, yet can't get the answer why my `LinearLayout` does not scroll, when its children happen to exceed the available screen room.

None of the provided answers did work. The funnies thing is, that I have also several other activities, with (I think) principally identical layout, and never had problems scrolling those.

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:statusBarBackground="@color/LightGreen1"
    tools:context="com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile.ActivityTeacherHwkAddTask">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="7dip">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/beforeSearchTabRow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/SeekTopicBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="?attr/actionModeSplitBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:elevation="15dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:onClick="onSeekTopicBoxClick"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:text="@string/seekTopic"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
                    android:elevation="17dp"
                    android:onClick="onSearchButtonClick"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default" />

            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/allTopics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
            android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
            android:text="@string/everything"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:onClick="onAllTopicsClick"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/SharpGreen1"
            android:elevation="7dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/GradeColumnLabel"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="@string/year_of_study"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TopicColumnLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="@string/topic"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/HomeworkColumnLabel"
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/homework"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TestColumnLabel"
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/test_short"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ListOfTopics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:elevation="7dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NoTasksMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:text="Nenašli sa žiadne úlohy .." />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addHomeworkBtn"
            style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:alpha="50"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:onClick="onSendButtonClick"
            android:text="@string/next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The layout looks like this:
[image]

The important part/object is:

> ListOfTopics << 
>   ,
>    into which I expand another items:  LinearLayouts with children.

This is what I expand/inject:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/schoolGrade"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
            android:text="Rocnik" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TopicName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Tema" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/SelectTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foregroundTint="@color/SharpGreen1"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColorLink="@color/SharpGreen1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/SelectHwk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:shadowColor="@color/SharpGreen1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Yes, I have tried to put the top `LinearLayout` named "ListOfTopics" container into a `ScrollView`, but does not help. And `LinearLayout` alone has intrinsic ability to scroll if needed.

I have spend hours of my life on this problem. Can anyone point out what do I do wrong, please ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not understand what is your problem. What exactly should scroll? Your item in ListView? Whole listView?

Comment: `And LinearLayout alone has intrinsic ability to scroll if needed.` where did you find this?

Comment: I have two more questions: Did you think of using RecyclerView/ListView instead of TableLayout? Did you try to set the layout_height parameter of LinearLayout of this"injected" layout?

Comment: @muminers
Yes, I'd like to scroll the yellow items in the main center of screen. They are LinearVievw in the outer LinearView. Possibly I could wrap my outer LinearView with ScrollView, but that does not work either - in this instance. In other activities it does. Can't figure the key difference.

Comment: But why are you trying to make item scrolling? It seems like very poor UX. Isn't it better to just expand the row and display all the text?

Comment: @mumines I'd like to scroll it vertically, not horizontally :) :)
I.e. not 1 item, but the whole yellow thing is to scroll, as many items are bellow the screen...
I may try the RecyclerView. Other stuff I have tried, but the thing is, THIS very same design works in another activity :-o  ... I have also such that are wrapped with ScrollView.

Comment: @Nfear
LinearLayout has scrolling methods, by which you can control scrolling programaticaly. And I think I have seen such statement somewhere on forum. Which might not be too relevant source, I agree. But this ain't scroll with a wrapper ScrollView either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it, or not, the "magic" to fix it is to change the top level [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) that I had, for something else. I tried [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), which scrolls well in other activities I already have.

`CoordinatorLayout` implements [NestedScrollingParent2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent2.html) interface, which assumes processing scroll events of nested containers with delegates, as I have learned.

The funny thing about it is, that even with `CoordinatorLayout` I was able to catch all touch/scroll events on nested views and process them manually (which is not what I prefer of course).

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to add listview in scrollview, you can try below code

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.paolorotolo.expandableheightlistview.ExpandableHeightListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">
      </com.github.paolorotolo.expandableheightlistview.ExpandableHeightListView></ScrollView>
```

This is working for me.
For this listview github link:
https://github.com/paolorotolo/ExpandableHeightListView